# How to ignore .*o*.cmd on a local linux repository?

Tags: linux, svn, linux-kernel, svnignore

I would like to ignore all files like .sddr09.o.cmd or .karma.o.cmd etc onto a kernel svn repository.

I try somme commands like :

```
svn propset svn:ignore '*.cmd' . --recursive
```

or

```
svn propset svn:ignore '*.o.cmd' . --recursive
```

or

```
svn propset svn:ignore '.*.o.cmd' . --recursive
```

but no one success to prevent from commit these files.

So I try to use the dontdiff file located in linux/Documentation/dontdiff appending

```
*.cmd
*.o.cmd
.*.o.cmd
```

at the end of the file

and I use the following command line :

```
svn propset svn:ignore -R -F Documentation/dontdiff .
```

but no more success.

Any Idea ?

Comment: Have you committed the result of `svn propset svn:ignore '*.cmd' .` ? The svn:ignore will not apply until you do that. Have you already added those files to the svn repo ? (svn:ignore only works for files that are not already added).

Comment: effectively I have already added my files. So I will make a delete, commit my modifications with svn:ignore, and it will be ok. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You mention in the comments that you've already added these files, so the first step is to undo that. Presumably you used [`svn add`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html) to add the files, so you'll need to use the inverse of that: [`svn delete`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.delete.html).

```
svn delete --keep-local path/to/file
```

The `--keep-local` will tell SVN not to undo any modifications you've made. If you do want to reset the files to their original state (or delete them if they didn't exist before), you can omit the option.

You can confirm this with [`svn status`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html). The files in question should not have anything in the first column.

After that, you should be able to run the [`svn ignore`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) commands that you included in your question.